# Why /home/.ecryptfs is missing inside dd image of LVM partition?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, dd, lvm, ecryptfs

## Disk Copy

2 month ago I backed up the 128G HDD of an old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 on it, using dd:

```
# sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img conv=noerror bs=128k  status=progress
```

Then I wiped the laptop 128G HDD and changed for new laptop.

*Today, I'd like to recover my old home folder from the dd image I made from the 128 HDD of the old laptop. I'm working from my new laptop (512G HDD), with ubuntu 17.04 on it.*

## Mouting

Here is my 128G dd image stored on my external HDD (Western Digital 1TB):

```
# file /media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img
/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

I link the dd image onto loopback device:

```
# losetup --partscan --find --show /media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img 
/dev/loop0
```

I check all losetup:

```
# losetup --all
/dev/loop0: [2049]:26922 (/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img)
```

I `fdisk` the loop0:

```
# sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00026d62

Device       Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/loop0p2      501758 250068991 249567234  119G  5 Extended
/dev/loop0p5      501760 250068991 249567232  119G 8e Linux LVM
```

Indeed, my backed up HDD was partitioned using LVM. Here is some `blkid` details:

```
# blkid
/dev/loop0: PTUUID="00026d62" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/loop0p1: UUID="77d30c72-6286-49b5-9954-10f7651ee5c2" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="00026d62-01"
/dev/loop0p5: UUID="nkDpfj-PptW-Zo21-GUPs-G6Ro-OdIT-0tFk6N" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="00026d62-05"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="0e1db479-955c-4964-8587-823e6cb15c98" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="3F7E-BC4A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="b4138b1c-f47a-4dd2-922e-c632e2712136"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="fc71fdfa-77ff-4104-95f6-6499348f2490" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2b783871-027c-4e97-8781-cfe7c67d52bb"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="blackWD" UUID="038764D1793B8A8D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0008c009-01"
```

[image]

Now map the devices using `kpartx`:

```
# kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

check result:

```
# sudo file -Ls /dev/mapper/*
/dev/mapper/control:           ERROR: cannot read `/dev/mapper/control' (Invalid argument)
/dev/mapper/loop0p1:           Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=77d30c72-6286-49b5-9954-10f7651ee5c2
/dev/mapper/loop0p2:           DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x8e, start-CHS (0x1f,59,29), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2, 249567232 sectors
/dev/mapper/loop0p5:           LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: nkDpfj-PptW-Zo21-GUPs-G6Ro-OdIT-0tFk6N, size: 127778422784
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:   Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: data
```

Check the status of LVM partitions with `lvdisplay`:

```
# lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                o20hjC-DEsi-Xtlb-z2J6-7Z1B-9tKl-4HzE17
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2014-03-29 01:34:48 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                111,29 GiB
  Current LE             28490
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                qhSxpL-pZAp-DUDi-aR7R-wCy1-w5JI-XCYNIn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2014-03-29 01:34:48 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                7,71 GiB
  Current LE             1974
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4
```

and `vgdisplay`:

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               119,00 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              30464
  Alloc PE / Size       30464 / 119,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               1qtlsn-vTuS-xPkL-wqwP-Gxvc-LUcm-sd68LV
```

I activate the LVM partitions with `vgchange`:

```
# vgchange -a y ubuntu-vg
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

I mount the root partition:

```
# mount -t ext4 -o ro,noload /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2
# ls /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2
boot  dev  home  proc  root  run  sys  tmp  var
```

## Problem

`.ecryptfs` is missing in the mounted LVM partition:

```
/home# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4,0K juin   2  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root   4,0K juin   2  2015 ..
dr-x------  2 victor victor 4,0K mars  29  2014 victor
```

whereas here is my current `/home` content:

```
/home# ls -ahl
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4,0K sept.  8 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root   4,0K oct.  11 11:22 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 root   root   4,0K sept.  8 11:35 .ecryptfs
drwx------ 41 victor victor  12K oct.  21 14:45 victor
```

And because this symlink didn't update:

```
# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor 32 mars  29  2014 /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
```

these two output are equal:

```
# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs/
total 20K
drwx------ 2 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:35 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-mount
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-umount
-rw------- 1 victor victor   13 sept.  8 11:35 Private.mnt
-rw------- 1 victor victor   34 sept.  8 11:35 Private.sig
-rw------- 1 victor victor   58 sept.  8 11:35 wrapped-passphrase
-rw-r--r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:48 .wrapped-passphrase.recorded
```

and my current home:

```
# ls -ahl /home/victor/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor 32 sept.  8 11:35 /home/victor/.ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
# ls -ahl /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
total 20K
drwx------ 2 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:35 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-mount
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-umount
-rw------- 1 victor victor   13 sept.  8 11:35 Private.mnt
-rw------- 1 victor victor   34 sept.  8 11:35 Private.sig
-rw------- 1 victor victor   58 sept.  8 11:35 wrapped-passphrase
-rw-r--r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:48 .wrapped-passphrase.recorded
```

**Where to look for the missing /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/.ecryptfs ?**

## HELP WOULD BE VERY APPRECIATED!

I have some very important files and memory pictures on the dd image...

Comment: I don't know the details of `ecryptfs` at all but quick network search makes me suspect `/home/.ecryptfs` may be just a (semi-temporary?) mountpoint. It looks like your current setup is very similar to the old one. What is the output of `mount` in your current OS? This may give us some clue.

Comment: Did you run `find` on the mounted image? Find anything named `.ecryptfs` or `*Private*`? What's in `[image]/home/victor`? Before making the backup & wiping the disk, did you try booting the old 16.04 & confirm that the home was actually encrypted? From here it looks like it might be just a regular non-encrypted home. Or was the `dd` image of the drive made while the drive itself was booted & running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't have a fully encrypted home, just a single encrypted directory (`.Private`) inside your home, probably created with `ecryptfs-setup-private`.

Supporting this is the `/media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs/` folder and it's contents, which look identical (plus a mystery zero byte `.wrapped-passphrase.recorded`) to what happens when you run `ecryptfs-setup-private` on a new unencrypted user.

If there is a `/media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.Private` directory I'd say it confirms this.

All you should need to do to decrypt your old files is have your old passphrase ready and run

```
ecryptfs-recover-private /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.Private
```